# Matlab system function with a C executable

Tags: c, matlab, system

I have written a Matlab GUI for my C program. I thought about using MEX, but there are too many C files and C program requires a DLL to run.

So, instead I have the Matlab System function calling the executable with inputs, something like `[status results] = system('executable "input 1" "input 2"')`, which runs well, but I want real time output. `results` is just a percent output of how complete the program is, and I want to use this output for a GUI progress bar in Matlab.

The output does get stored into `results`, but only after the program is complete. Thus, making the progress bar pointless.

Is it possible to get the executable to send outputs one at a time to Matlab, and then have Matlab update the progress bar, and return to the executable?

Edit: I'm looking for a solution in Windows.

Comment: I don't understand all your question, because I am not very familiar with Matlab. However, did you perhaps consider using http://www.scilab.org/ ?

Comment: I have not considered scilab. I wish I could choose which environment I could program in, but that choice is not mine to make. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: A much simpler implementation would be to have the executable write a file whose name reports the completion status, and Matlab reading the file name every second or so.

Comment: @Jonas, simpler indeed, although doesn't sound very elegant or efficient. I could imagine the costs of creating and destroying a file are much higher than reading from the command line (if that's even possible). I suppose I'll do that if I get desperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found a solution. Credit goes to Richard Alcock at Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4828-reading-from-comand-prompt-executables)

Specifically, for my solution:

```
cmd = {'executable.exe', 'input 1', 'input 2'};
processBuilder = java.lang.ProcessBuilder(cmd);
cmdProcess = processBuilder.start();

% Set up a reader to read the output from the command prompt
reader = 
    java.io.BufferedReader(...
        java.io.InputStreamReader(...
            cmdProcess.getInputStream() ...
        ) ...
    );

% Loop until there is some output
nextLine = char( reader.readLine );
while isempty(nextLine) 
    nextLine = char( reader.readLine );
end

% Then loop until there is no more output
while ~isempty(nextLine);
    fprintf('Output: %s\n', nextLine);
    nextLine = char( reader.readLine );
end

% Get the exit value of the process
exitValue = cmdProcess.exitValue
```

Note: this code does not hold up the executable. The executable must finish before this code finishes, otherwise this code crashes when it gets ahead of the executable.

Answer (score 2):

I only see two options, and neither fits directly with your current implementation approach.

The first, is to just use sockets to communicate between the two.  Here's a pure matlab socket implementation, but under the hood it's using C sockets.  It's been 10 years since I've done C/Java socket comms, but I recall that at the time there were some issues.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21131-tcpip-socket-communications-in-matlab

Another option is to have your executable be accessible via a C DLL from matlab, and call the DLL directly from matlab (i.e. have matlab control your app).  This is the way I've been doing most such interactions lately, and it works very well.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/loadlibrary.html

Comment: check out the solution at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/4828-reading-from-comand-prompt-executables, it may be of interest to you. Thanks for your answers though.

Comment: I've not been following the Java world for a while, and so I forget that you have an entire JVM at your disposal.  That's a cool link!  Thanks.